# Make new table with every CSV import-MS Access

Tags: ms-access

Is it possible to make table everytime a CSV is imported? I have 4 tables imported from CSV's with different names and I have created a new table(**Reporting**) out of them using a make table Query. Now I want to delete the 4 Tables and import 4 new CSV's and make another new table out of them say (Reporting 2) and I want to continue the process to make more Reporting Tables. I have tried with a code But I cannot seem to get a new Reporting Table Everytime. Where am I going wrong?

```
SELECT WebLife_Statistik.Antragsnummer, [WebLife_Statistik.Datum] & "-" &     [WebLife_Statistik.Zeit] AS [Ausgang Datenstrom WebLife], [ZW_Testdaten.Datum] & "-" & [ZW_Testdaten.Zeit] AS [Eingang Datenstrom Z-Workflow],     [Vs_anlage_schwebe.Datum] & "-" & [Vs_anlage_schwebe.Zeit] AS [Anlage Schwebe VSL], [Vs_annahme_police.Datum] & "-" & [Vs_annahme_police.Zeit] AS [Policierung VSL] INTO Reporting
```

Comment: not sure if you gave the complete sql. But the current sql you stated above is missing the source tables to get those information you stated on SELECT clause

Comment: Having trouble understanding your work flow here. So you delete the tables, in order to recreate them with a new name? And you want to keep making the same table over and over again with a new name?

Comment: Yeah the names of the 4 tables are WebLife_Statistik,  ZW_Testdaten, Vs_anlage_schwebe, Vs_annahme_police. I want to Delete these tables after creating Reporting table and I want to reimport 4 tables with same names as these but with different data and make another Reporting table (say Reporting2) and want to repeat this procedure.

Comment: When you reimport it is exactly the same format every time?

Comment: yes its the exact same format.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be a better, more normalized approach.

You have 4 tables:

```
WebLife_Statistik
ZW_Testdaten
Vs_anlage_schwebe 
Vs_annahme_police
```

Seems the only reason you are deleting the tables is to delete the data. So simply do that :

```
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM WebLife_Statistik"
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM ZW_Testdaten"
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM Vs_anlage_schwebe"
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM Vs_annahme_police"
```

Now you can safely import your next 4 tables into these tables, reusing them.

Next should probably be your biggest change, the `Reporting` table. I would add a useful primary key to help differentiate the data.

MyTable before

```
Field1
Field2
Field3
```

MyTable after

```
KeyID
Field1
Field2
Field3
```

When you insert into this Reporting table, each new insert has a new key, that uniquely differentiates the data. This way you can recall any previous report by simply supplying the proper `KeyID`, ie...

```
SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3 WHERE KeyID = 5;
```

This allows you to reuse your tables, which is better design.